# Do you "take out a debt" or "draw a debt" or some other phrasing?

Tags: phrases

I wish to say that I did something which put me in debt to someone, without naming the person. How would I phrase this?

Example:
But one afternoon near the end of my time on the farm, *I took out a new debt*.

EDIT: the debt is not literal (i.e. $), it is figurative.

Comment: You "incur" debt all at once, usually, but you can "draw it down" by paying it off over time.

Comment: You can *take on* debt in the sense of accepting a challenge (or of assuming someone else's debt), but you would *take out* the instrument of debt— a mortgage, a bond, a line of credit, a loan, etc.

Comment: Thanks choster, that distinction is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You could use "take out a [***loan***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/loan?q=take+out+a+loan)":

> A thing that is borrowed, especially a sum of money that is expected
>   to be paid back with interest: ‘borrowers can ***take out a loan*** for
>   £84,000’

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

[***Take out a loan***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+out+a+loan) is broadly used:

> to get a loan of money, especially from a bank. Mary took out a loan
>   to buy a car. We will have to take out a loan to remodel the kitchen.

[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.]

You could also consider "go into [***debt***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/debt)":

> She went into debt to pay for college.

[Merriam-Webster]

Or "incur debt" as suggested in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Answering these questions would add context to aid in obtaining the most appropriate or best wording:

Is/was this a literal (i.e., monetary) debt, an actual loan (casual, or formally documented)?

Is/was the debt in the form of money or property because you damaged property (intentionally, or by accident/due to carelessness)?

Or is/was it more in the figurative sense, as a moral obligation ('debt') incurred due to something you did or said that was offensive?  Or, in the positive sense, is/was it the proverbial 'debt of gratitude' due to some act of kindness by the other person preventing loss, injury, or embarrassment to you?